# Where is $(B∩A')$ on a Venn diagram?

Tags: statistics

I have this Venn diagram with a circle being A and a circle being B.

I've been asked to find the number of the union of B and A'. I understand that A∩B is the middle of the two circles, but which part of the Venn diagram is the union of B and not-A?

Thank you!

Comment: Is $A'$ supposed to be to complement of $A$ in a certain set? Then you have to "draw" this set too. And it should be $A,B\subseteq X$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(B∩A')$ means: inside $B$ and outside $A$.

Comment: So the entire B circle, but excluding the bit where the two circles overlap?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Shade everything in the circle $B$ and then shade everything *outside* the circle $A$, and it's the region that has been shaded twice.